# Using gatsby-source-graphcms with gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: GraphCMS_Locale variable type issue

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, i18next, react-i18next

I've run into an challenge/posible incompatibility between gatsby-source-graphcms and gatsby-plugin-react-i18next, for which there appears to be virtually no information online and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this before please.

I'm working on adding localisation to a site which uses gatsby-source-graphcms and the Gatsby File System Route API to build pages dynamically. Everything was going fine, until I tried to use the `$language` GraphQL query variable made available by gatsby-plugin-react-i18next with the `locale` filter field in GraphCMS, which yielded this error message:

`Variable "$language" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "GraphCMS_Locale"`

The one and only reference I've been able to find to a similar issue was on GraphCMS' public Slack, where someone referred to abandoning gatsby-source-graphcms I favour of gatsby-source-graphql due to this. However I'm hesitant to do this, as that would basically means re-writing the entire site for me!

I've been trying to find some way to feed the page query a second variable, which duplicates the value `$language` variable from gatsby-plugin-react-i18next but is declared as the correct data type for GraphCMS, or perhaps to somehow cast the string to `GraphCMS_locale` but have had no luck so far.

Has anyone found a way to make gatsby-source-graphcms play nicely with gatsby-plugin-react-i18next please?

The WIP code for this can be seen here: https://github.com/binghamchris/paddelbuch/blob/feature-i18n/src/pages/index.js

Apologies if the code is a bit bad somewhere. I'm not a web dev (this is a community project I'm volunteering on, where there's no professional web devs) and am really just hacking away on copy-and-paste code

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer

Answer (score 0):

I found a super hacky workaround, inspired by @notrab's kind help, in case it helps anyone else:
I added the following to gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({
  actions: { createTypes, printTypeDefinitions }
}) => {
  createTypes(`
  type Locale implements Node {
    language: GraphCMS_Locale
  }
  `);
};
```

This changes the GraphQL data type on the `language` field in the i18next translation data to `GraphCMS_Locale`, which then means both data types needed by both `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` and `gatsby-source-graphcms` match... and so far it seems to be working in dev mode!